# Bleeeet Bleeeet Bl Bleet!

Tags: code-golf, string

(Meaning: Convert English to Bleet)

We have praised goats as god for years now.

But if we can't translate English to 'Bleet', the Goat God's language, we cannot communicate with them.

So, to communicate with them, we have researched the activities of goats, and retrieved this pattern, which is the core of the language.

> Say 'Bleet' for the length of each words. That means the amount of 'e's should be (length-3) for words longer than 3 letters.You shall cut down 'Bleet' for words shorter than 'Blt'. For example, 'be' becomes 'bl', but 'cat' and 'boat' becomes 'blt' and 'blet'.

As it seems, they don't actually change non-alphabet characters to 'Bleet'. Our research showed that 'Hello, World!' to Bleet is 'Bleet, Bleet!' not 'Bleeet Bleeet'. Also, The goats are not so intelligent(no offense), so they don't  seem to understand non-ascii characters or diacritics at all.

Now, It's time to make a translator to communicate with the goat gods.

### Bleeeeet (Meaning: Examples)

```
Hello, World! => Bleet, Bleet!
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. => Bleet Bleet Bleet Blt Blet.
We praise the Goat God! => Bl Bleeet Blt Blet Blt!
I have a pen => B Blet B Blt
0123456789_ => 0123456789_
0te_st1 => 0Bl_Bl1
```

Comment: What formats of input are acceptable

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk any form of string input.

Comment: What should we do for single letter words

Comment: Can the input contain diacritics (i.e. `é`, `ê`, `ë`, `ñ`, etc.)?

Comment: [Related!](https://youtu.be/wMEOzUdxHs4)

Comment: And what about words containing apostrophes? Will `it's` become `Blt` or `Bl't` or `Bl'B`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Good point. I'll change the post a bit to apply that.

Comment: Looks like you just invalidated every answer.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Should I rollback the rules? or let them change it?

Comment: It's up to you, but if you keep it I'd notify every answerer. If it were me I think I'd probably allow any behaviour: pass them (`Jimmy's`:`Bleee't`), treat them as word separations (`Jimmy's`:`Bleet'B`), or treat them as part of words (`Jimmy's`:`Bleeeet`). If I had to choose one I'd go with the word separator option, since it's what the 6 answers do.

Comment: @MatthewRoh The apostrophe and dash exception invalidates most of the current answers. I'd suggest making it an optional requirement.

Comment: Shouldn’t `0te_st1` be `0Bl_et1` -- does an underscore separate words?

Comment: Rolled back. Now it should be significantly easier.

Comment: This is really good challenge, we should have more like this.

Comment: @Downgoat quality-wise, or goat-wise?

Answer (score 13):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 31 bytes

```
T`lL`e
(?<!e)e
B
Be
Bl
e(?!e)
t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#DcvLCsIwEEbh/TzFdFdBpPVaQSh0o4JLocs20B8amJiQjL5@zObAtzj5PctrBtX9rcIGNNBQIoS6LybN@QERv@XRR1kqEh/h2Ib0dbz4Ik5W2TjojkZwiMYmsK7guzdaUp4nr@YHNhzwoabdH46n86W7TtQopqTtHw)

#### Explanation

```
T`lL`e
```

Turn all letters into `e`s.

```
(?<!e)e
B
```

Turn the first `e` in each run into `B`.

```
Be
Bl
```

Turn `Be` into `Bl`.

```
e(?!e)
t
```

Turn the last `e` in each run into `t`.

Comment: `T1L` the `T` stage "wraps" the translation pairs so that you can turn all letters like that to `e`

Comment: @ConorO'Brien It's actually a lower-case `l`, not a `1`, but I'm not sure what you mean by "wrap". Transliteration simply repeats the last character in the target pattern, so if it was `T\`lL\`ef`, you'd map `a` to `e` and all other letters to `f`, not alternatingly to `e` and `f`.

Comment: it was a bad joke. Sorry

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>79</s> <s>77</s> 74 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/[A-Z]+/gi,x=>x.replace(/./g,(_,i)=>'Bl'[i]||'et'[+!x[i+1]]))
```

Alternate approach, currently <s>83</s> 78 bytes:

```
s=>s.replace(/[A-Z]+/gi,x=>`Bl${'e'.repeat((l=x.length)>3&&l-3)}t`.slice(0,l))
```

The best I could do recursively was 88 bytes:

```
f=([c,...s],i=0,q=/^[A-Z]/i)=>c?q.test(c)?('Bl'[i]||'te'[+q.test(s)])+f(s,i+1):c+f(s):''
```

Comment: I came up with `'Blet'[i>1?2+!x[i+1]:i]` but sadly it's the same length.

Comment: @Neil Yeah, I figured it would be possible to do it that way, but I'm surprised it was nearly shorter than the way I'm doing it.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>115</s> <s>88</s> <s>86</s> <s>77</s> 75 bytes

`preg_replace` with arrays (requires PHP 5.4 or later)

```php
echo preg_replace(["#[a-z]#i","#(?<!e)e#",_Be_,"#e(?!e)#"],[e,B,Bl,t],$argn);
```

Run with `echo '<string>' | php -nR '<code>'` or [test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/334c9595c1b546d163fbd0a44ad877804fa5d97c).

**breakdown**

```
SEARCH      EXPLANATION             REPLACE     EXAMPLE
            original string                     Hello
[a-z]       every letter            e           eeeee
(?<!e)e     first letter            B           Beeee
Be          first two letters       Bl          Bleee
e(?!e)      last letter if still e  t           Bleet
```

Revision 5: saved 9 bytes with [Martin Ender´s regex chain](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112556/55735).
<sup>(That also fixed cases with non-alphabetic word characters = digits/underscores.)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>135</s> 128 bytes

```hs
b"e"="B"
b"ee"="Bl"
b('e':_:_:e)="Bl"++e++"t"
b e=e
e!(l:t)|elem l$['a'..'z']++['A'..'Z']=('e':e)!t|1<3=b e++l:""!t
e!_=[]
(""!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#nY4xCsMwDEX3nMIRBcUIAqWbiYb2GDUmxEWBgJOheCq5u6u40LkULU9ffPFKBAGGGzQKlZJih4Ju1BFbEyIhgqwXIyyNtF1y2e6SZDXp5HHCvscXBiKP14PvGLg@Edvm/TxcWJtEyQG0Wfsj@9DM3Olqyzotm2GzbFme0yObufwjFX@Xil8p51P4OMXDKVapyMNg@@r2Bg) Usage `(""!) $ "some string"`. Without regexes, this turned out to be quite long, maybe some other approach is shorter. Edit: Saved 7 bytes thanks to @nimi!

Comment: Renaming function `b` to `a` you can apply it immediately when constructing the resulting string and omit the final `=<<`: `b!(l:t)|...|1<3=a b++l:""!t;b!_=a b;(""!)`.

Comment: Doesn't work online for It's Jimmy's test  I get Bl'B Bleet'B

Comment: @cleblanc This requirement was added after my answer and invalidates most of the current answers ... let me ask the OP.

Comment: @Laikoni Right.  I came late to this game and the apostrophe is a particularly difficult exception to handle.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 84 Bytes

```
<?=preg_replace(["#[a-z]#i","#(?<!l)l#","#(?<=l)l#","#e(?!e)#"],[l,B,e,t],$argv[1]);
```

## PHP, 117 Bytes

```
<?=preg_replace_callback("#[a-z]+#i",function($m){return substr(str_pad(Bl,-1+$l=strlen($m[0]),e).t,0,$l);},$argv[1]);
```

Comment: Save one byte with `-1+$l=...`

Comment: @Titus nice and I Have found a better solution

Comment: Zwei Dumme - ein Gedanke. :) But `\bl` fails for non-alphabetic word characters: `_we_`. You need an explicit assertion: `(?<!l)l`. Same for `e\b` -> `e(?!e)` (+7 bytes)

Comment: @Titus In the meantime it is myself noticed that my thought was wrong. And I love your german comment.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 47 bytes

Saved 15 bytes by using the same technique as Martin Ender's [Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112556/55508). (This answer is basically a port of his answer now)

46 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
s/\pl/e/g;s/(?<!e)e/B/g;s/Be/Bl/g;s/e(?!e)/t/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#HYvLCsIwEEX3@Yopbiqo0/oWBaEb9Qu6EUqgl7YwNSEZ/f0aurmcc@AuMo8gtPZT5LcXBnfXyPn9lmEJrmarEshMyO@ps3I3TU@IuBXVLkibGXEBIw0@fkdqXTKKg5IdoRtTg3ywQwRpD3o4q2nS50W9/YEseXxMUW53@8PxdL40plA0Ucs/)

---

Older versions: 62 bytes:

```perl
s/\pl+/$l=length$&;$_=Bl.e x($l-3).t;chop while$l<y%%%c;$_/ge
```

And 68 bytes:

```perl
s%\pl+%$_=$&;s/./B/;s/.\K./l/;s/(?<=..).(?=.)/e/g;s/..\K.$/t/;$_%ge
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>120</s> <s>151</s> <s>140</s> <s>111</s> <s>108</s> <s>105</s> <s>104</s> <s>92</s> 90 Bytes

Working for "It's Jimmy's test" --> Bl'B Bleet'B Blet

```
j;f(char*m){for(;*m=!isalpha(*m++)?j=0,*(m-1):"*Blet"[isalpha(*m)?j^3?++j:j:j>1?4:++j];);}
```

The output is now a side effect by destroying the original string.

```
main(c,v)char**v;{
    char test[] = "The End is near Fellows!";
    f(test);puts(test);
    char test2[] = "We praise the Goat God!";
    f(test2);puts(test2);
    char test3[] = "It's Jimmy's test";
    f(test3);puts(test3);
    char test4[] = "0te_st1";
    f(test4);puts(test4);
    char test5[] = "I have a pen";
    f(test5);puts(test5);
    char test6[] = "_0123456789_";
    f(test6);puts(test6);
}
```

I think it's correct at least now

```
Blt Blt Bl Blet Bleeeet!
Bl Bleeet Blt Blet Blt!
Bl'B Bleet'B Blet
0Bl_Bl1
B Blet B Blt
_012345678_
```

Comment: [Jimmy](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/72958/9994)?

Comment: @DLosc I haven't gone mad and died yet.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7, <strike>129</strike> <strike>118</strike> <strike>114</strike> <strike>109</strike> <strike>95</strike> <strike>91</strike> 88 bytes

```
import re
s=re.sub
def f(i):print s(r"e\b","t",s("Be","Bl",s(r"\be","B",s("\w","e",i))))
```

Just an `re.sub` chain

#### Step by step

Example input: "**We praise the Goat God!**"

---

**Alias sub so we can save bytes on repeated calls**

```
import re
s=re.sub
```

**Replace all word characters with "e"**

`s("\w","e",i)`

Output: `ee eeeeee eee eeee eee!`

**Replace all "e"s which are preceded by a word boundary (Beginning of word) with "B"**

`s(r"\be","B",s("\w","e",i))`

Output: `Be Beeeee Bee Beee Bee!`

**Replace all "Be" with "Bl"**

`s("Be","Bl",s(r"\be","B",s("\w","e",i)))`

Output: `Bl Bleeee Ble Blee Ble!`

**Replace all "e"s which are followed by a word boundary with "t"**

`s(r"e\b","t",s("Be","Bl",s(r"\be","B",s("\w","e",i))))`

Output: `Bl Bleeet Blt Blet Blt!`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! We allow functions to print their results, so replacing `return` with `print` should save a byte.

Comment: You can also remove the leading `r` from raw strings if they have no backlashes in them saving another 3 bytes

Comment: Thanks @ConorO'Brien ! I was able to simplify a piece of the regex (which ended up needing an `r`) and I got it down to 95 bytes. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Alright I got it down to 88 bytes and I think that's the best I can do here

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 271 bytes

I am aware that this is rather long and I welcome suggestions on how to reduce the length.

```python
def f(s):
 b=[];t='';f=[];a=list.append
 for c in s:
  if c.isalpha():t+='e'
  else:
   if t:a(b,t);t=''
    a(b,c)
 if t:a(b,t)
 for i in b:
  i=[*i]
  if i[0]=='e':
   i[0]='B';i[-1]=[i[-1],'t'][len(i)>2]
   if len(i)>2:i[1]='l'
  a(f,''.join(i))
 return ''.join(f)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I see a couple golfs you could make.  You can visit our [tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) page for a list of useful tips for golfing in Python.

Comment: instead of `x.append(y)` or in your case, `a(x,y)`, you can do `x+=y,` (comma required)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>137</s> 114 bytes

```python
def f(s,r='',l=-3):
 for c in s+'\0':
	if c.isalpha():l+=1
	else:r+=('Bl%st'%('e'*l))[:l+3*(l>=0)]+c;l=-3
 print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#HYxBCsMgFETX9RR/E77GVFKys9hFr9GWIolS4ScRNfT4aSzMDPNgmH1yHjzPXTKIHZnzIDQDvyYYISyQJT571OwUPIwqZEvxY7nQJM2FnRxlp5M0HO/U5IINR4ctCfE4BkPL6WZ68ZLjtf4yiCksBdLuebLfd1jiVrgQO63JzRBi3maY1oMghwJ2dkWBBVv195GhYK5VKVX5Bw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 28 bytes

```
aR+XA{Y'eX#a-3\"Bl\yt\"@<#a}
```

Takes input as a command-line argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@58YpB3hWB2pnhqhnKhrHKPklBNTWRKj5GCjnFj7//9/x0T1RIXERDCGEFDSQxEA)

#### Explanation

This was fun--I got to use regex modifiers and string interpolation.

```
                              a is 1st cmdline arg; XA is the regex `[A-Za-z]` (implicit)
aR                            In a, replace
   XA                          the regex XA
  +                            wrapped in (?:  )+
     {                     }  with this callback function:
          #a-3                 Length of argument - 3
       'eX                     Repeat e that many times (empty string if #a-3 is negative)
      Y                        Yank that string into the y variable
              \"Bl\yt\"        An escaped string, which interpolates the value of y
                       @<#a    Take first len(a) characters
                              After the replacement, the string is autoprinted
```

Answer (score 1):

## [stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 57 bytes

```
'\l+'{!n size 2-:4\^5*1+3/\1<-4 tb 0\,'Blet'\#''join}repl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#fVBLT8JAEL7vr/gaDgNSkPLwQcREDj4Sbx64NJIVxrS6ZZvuYoiE3w67LZpqopfZ@R4zm/madM9K6RAzXahlQAKkdMEZ0tysMyy1QzCphczYdr08Y@SFTA3DJow7La0r1eQDEvnBkMh55XEv6g@Go7Pzi8t5CS3PjY0ILWyxwRibPcWqTdtg5b74ZPQ742H8PDqJ2oPTOLrqDGFf0ItDmiq2FDeI3nS62hWcq/0GMUIQJteueBo7ZDLH422FeJFoD/Taip83@hG3kG1YPYH45@Jv869adrYr/kijGivdNbtvAlFPqfQdNa@KWmReq0FxjK@kp2o@VS7JCZr0pDPGIuHFu8GrTBUvCXSj1BeXS2Mc13KBNXwc@wM) Takes input from the top of the stack.

Let **a**(**n**) = [A136412](https://oeis.org/A136412)(**n** - 2) = (5 × 4<sup>**n** − 2</sup> + 1) ÷ 3. Converting **a**(**n**) to base 4 yields:

```
a(3) = 134
a(4) = 1234
a(5) = 12234
a(6) = 122234
...
```

Mapping indices 0..3 to the string `Blet`, we get:

```
a(3) = lt
a(4) = let
a(5) = leet
a(6) = leeet
...
```

Now, prepending `B` gives us the desired string, given the length. Mostly. One just needs to handle the special cases for **n** ≤ 2. In my case, this is solved by subtracting (**n** − 2 < 1) as a numeric boolean (1 for "true" and 0 for "false").

As for the specifics of the answer:

```
'\l+'{! ... }repl
             repl    replace all
'\l+'                alphanumeric strings ("letters")
     {!     }        applying this function to the result.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 201 bytes

```java
String c(String s){String r="",z="e([^e]|$)";char p=0;int x;for(char c:s.toCharArray()){x=c&~32;p=x>64&x<91?p==66?'l':p>100&p<109?'e':66:c;r+=p;}return r.replaceAll("l"+z,"lt$1").replaceAll(z,"et$1");}
```

Not really happy with it, and can certainly be golfed some more..

**Explanation:**

```java
String c(String s){               // Method with String parameter and String return-type
  String r="",                    //  The return-String
         z="e([^e]|$)";           //  Partial regex String that's used twice ('e' followed by non-'e' or nothing)
  char p=0;                       //  The previous character
  int x;                          //  Another temp value
  for(char c : s.toCharArray()){  //  Loop over the characters of the input String
    x = c&~32;                    //   Make every lowercase character uppercase (this returns an integer, hence the integer temp value, which is shorter than a cast to char)
    p = x>64 & x<91 ?             //   If the current character is a letter:
         p == 66 ?                //    And if the previous character is 'B':
          'l'                     //     Set the character value to 'l'
         : p>100&p<109 ?          //    Else if the previous character is either an 'e' or 'l':
            'e'                   //     Set the character value to 'e'
           :                      //    Else:
            66                    //     Set the character value to 'B'
         :                        //   Else (not a letter):
          c;                      //    Set the character to the current character
    r += p;                       //   Append the result-String with this character
  }                               //  End loop
  return r                        //  Return the result-String
    .replaceAll("l"+z,"lt$1")     //   After we've replaced all occurrences of "le." with "lt." (where "." can be anything else, including nothing at the end of a line)
    .replaceAll(z,"et$1")         //   And also replaced all occurrences of "ee." with "et." (where "." can again be anything else)
}                                 // End of method
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/WjcpbS)

```java
class M{
  static String c(String s){String r="",z="e([^e]|$)";char p=0;int x;for(char c:s.toCharArray()){x=c&~32;p=x>64&x<91?p==66?'l':p>100&p<109?'e':66:c;r+=p;}return r.replaceAll("l"+z,"lt$1").replaceAll(z,"et$1");}

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c("Hello, World!"));
    System.out.println(c("lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."));
    System.out.println(c("We praise the Goat God!"));
    System.out.println(c("I have a pen"));
    System.out.println(c("0123456789_"));
    System.out.println(c("0te_st1"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```java
Bleeet, Bleeet!
Bleeet Bleeet Bleeet Blt Bleet.
Bl Bleeeet Blt Bleet Blt!
B Bleet B Blt
0123456789_
0Bl_Bl1
```

Comment: `s.split("")` instead of `s.toCharArray()` saves some I believe

Comment: @KritixiLithos I tried it, but then I have the issue of checking if the String is a letter (`x=c&~32` won't work on a String, and `x>64&x<91` both won't work anymore). If you can make it shorter with the split let me know, though.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 36 bytes

```
lDAsSå.¡€g£vyAySåPigÍ<'e×"Blÿt"yg£}J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@5/j4lgcfHip3qGFj5rWpB9aXFbpWAnkB2SmH@61UU89PF3JKefw/hKlSqBcrdf//wYlqfHFJYYA)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#qymrrAz9n@PiWBx8eKneoYWPmtakH1pcVulYCeQHZKYf7rVRTz08Xckp5/D@EqVKoFyt1//aCKXD@60UDu9X0vnvkZqTk6@jEJ5flJOiyJWTX5Saq5BZUFyaq5CSD@QpFGeWKCTmppbocYWnKhQUJWYWpyqUZKQquOcnlgAJoB5PhYzEslSFRIWC1DwuA0MjYxNTM3MLy3gug5LU@OISQwA)

**Explanation**

Prepare input:

```
lD                                    # convert input to lower-case and duplicate
  As                                  # push lower-case alphabet and swap input to the top
    Så                                # check each char in input for 
                                      # membership in the alphabet
      .¡                              # split into chunks of equal elements
        €g                            # get length of each chunk
          £                           # split input into chunks of those lengths
```

This creates a list such as `['hello', ', ', 'world', '!']`
 for the input `Hello, World!`

Iterate over list:

```
v                          # for each element in the list
 y                         # push current element
  AySåPi               }   # if all members of current element are letters
        gÍ<'e×             # repeat string "e" len(element)-3 times
              "Blÿt"       # replace "ÿ" with the e's in the string "Blÿt"
                    yg£    # take the first len(element) chars of the string
                        J  # join to string
```

Answer (score 0):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-E`, 58 bytes

Port of [Martin Ender's Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112556/11261).

```
s/[a-z]/e/gi
s/(^|[^e])e/\1B/g
s/Be/Bl/g
s/e([^e]|$)/t\1/g
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlWbSSrqtS7IKlpSVpuhY3rYr1oxN1q2L1U_XTM7mK9TXiaqLjUmM1U_VjDJ3004EiTqn6TjlgVqoGSKpGRVO_JMZQPx1iAtSgBdvDUxUKihIzi1MVSjJSFdzzE0uARIoiRBoA)